# Deriving Kepler's First Law from Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation: Interpretation of the $u = 1/r$ change of variable

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

I'm working through a somewhat [unsatisfying derivation](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/KeplersLaws.htm) of Kepler's First Law from Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation. The key to obtaining the equation of motion that you can solve lies in making the change of variable $u = 1/r$ in the angular momentum of mass $m$, $L = m r^2 \omega$, which is conveniently treated as a point mass. I see the mathematical necessity of this, but what is the physical interpretation (if any)? Is this necessary because the gravitational potential of mass $m$ is $1 / r$ for large $r$?

Comment: There is no necessity for a physical interpretation of a change of variable. Physics is *invariant* under changes of coordinates, the same things happen regardless of which coordinates we choose, so I don't know what you're asking for.

Comment: A thorough walkthrough *all* the steps in the descriptions of classical $f(r)$ potentials, orbits, equations of motion, Kepler's laws and all the rest can be found in the standard http://www.amazon.com/Classical-Mechanics-Edition-Herbert-Goldstein/dp/0201657023

Comment: @ACuriousMind, thank you for the reminder about invariance. Just like a wise choice of coordinate system, a similar wise choice of integration variable will ease the interpretation of your result.